# If using docker, is the capacity of database in SQL Server unlimited?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am trying to install and use SQL Server on docker.

[image]

As far as I know, 10GB is available for free on Express.

Is it the same for Docker?

If so, can I use unlimited capacity if I select MSSQL_PID as 'standard' in the environment variable?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short the answer to your question is yes, what ever version you mention in the PID variable the sql server will operate like that. The only thing about licensing is that it believe on you that you have proper prior licensing for that version though it doesn't have any technical check or verification process.

Following link will give you some more related information that may help you further -

https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/200